# typescript - How to enforce object destructuring in functions

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I am working with playwright e2e testing, and I noticed that when trying to use `beforeEach` as a function of my own without destructing the `page` from the `args` property

```
test.beforeEach((args, testInfo) => {
    console.log('heyo');
  });
```

i got the following error:

```
 npm run test

> e2e@1.0.0 test
> playwright test

Error: First argument must use the object destructuring pattern: args
  defined at playwright/appName.test.ts:7:8
```

I want to have the same functionality in my functions (to enforce using destructuring) how can I achieve this?

I tried digging through the playwright code to understand how they did it without success.

Comment: What do you use for linting? For eslint you can take inspiration from https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md which does this for react components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What playwright does is looking at the source code of the function at runtime, and doing some rudimentary parsing to check and enforce the destructing.

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/233664bd30c137159df02c1dd58f4e5391e9fa20/packages/playwright-test/src/fixtures.ts#L427-L443

The important bits:

```js
// get me the code
const text = fn.toString();
```

```js
// after naive parsing, check if we are destructing
  if (firstParam[0] !== '{' || firstParam[firstParam.length - 1] !== '}')
    addFatalError('First argument must use the object destructuring pattern: '  + firstParam, location);
```

Do no attempt to do this, unless you have a solid reason to do so